# Shifting 1001 certain value gives a different result than expected

Tags: c++, c++11

I am doing the following. I would like to shift 1001 to the left

```
int a = 0;
a = (1001 << 2);
std::cout << a; //Gives 4004
```

I was expecting it to be in binary `100100` which is 36.
Why am I getting `0000111110100100`?

Comment: `1001` isn't a binary constant...

Comment: ah ok so you are basically saying its considering 1001 as a decimal ? I was under the impression that if 1 << 2 works then 1001 would work as well

Comment: All constants, unless prefixed accordingly, are decimal.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Can you put that as an answer ?

Comment: Okay, posted an answer.

Comment: `1 << 2` "works" because the number one is written the same way in binary and decimal. The `1` in the expression is the decimal `1`. (How would you write the number "one thousand and one" in your code if `1001` were a binary number?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1001` is a decimal constant. All integers literals are decimal unless prefixed accordingly. If you wish to obtain a binary constant, then prefix it with `0b` (only available since C++14 though).

```
a = (0b1001 << 2);
```

Otherwise, hexadecimal is a decent alternative:

```
a = (0x9 << 2);
```